# Save master and details in DRF with foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save a entity from a request.

I have two models

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    userReservation = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    dateStart = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, default=datetime.now)  

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class DetailsReservation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='reservation_details')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='products_reservation')
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_Description +" by: " + self.userbyReserva.email

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.userbyReserva = self.Reservation.userReservation
        super(DetailsReservation, self).save(args, kwargs)
```

Then i have two serializers

```
class DetailsReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DetailsReservation
        fields = '__all__'


class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reservation_details = DetailsReservationSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = '__all__'
```

then in my views, i have

```
class makereservation(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        data["userReservation"] = request. user.id
        serializer = ReservationSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am trying with postman (for emulate request type post)

this is my json

```
{
    "dateStart": "2020-09-20T13:00:00-05:00",
    "reservation_details": [{
            "product": 1,
            "Quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "Quantity": 2
        }, {
            "productId": 3,
            "Quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

but i don't know, how save this.

- first, i tried to save Reservation, after obtain these is, and with id tried insert DetailsReservation, but doesn't working

Comment: You're trying to create a `Reservation` and many `DetailsReservation` objects using nested data and a single request, correct? Also when you say it's not "working" what is it doing (and if there's an error message, what is the message)?

Comment: yes Mr,  One reservation, and many details_reservations with a single request, but when sending request, it show me this error "The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default."

Answer (score 3):

Django Rest Framework does not have built-in support for creating nested objects. However they do provide some documentation for adding this functionality here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

You'll have to add creation functionality for the `DetailsReservation` within the `ReservationSerializer`'s create method after creating the `Reservation` object.

Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reservation_details = DetailsReservationSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        details_data = validated_data.pop('reservation_details') #grab the data on details
        reservation = Reservation.objects.create(**validated_data) # create the master reservation object
        for reservation_detail in details_data:
            # create a details_reservation referencing the master reservation
            DetailsReservation.objects.create(**reservation_detail, reservation=reservation)
        return reservation
```

Also one small note, I'd recommend renaming `Reservation` and `Quantity` in `DetailsReservation` to be lowercased as they refer to instances, not classes. My code works once that change is made, however, changing `reservation=reservation` in the `DetailsReservation.objects.create` call to `Reservation=reservation` will make the code work with your code in its current state.